# Content from external page to new page

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a table from **`proxy.php`** to **`index.html`**, but this table contains some attributes that I want to remove first. But that is where i am stuck, I don't know how to remove these attributes.

On `proxy.php`, I grab the html from the target url.

```
<?php
    $url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $html;
?>
```

On `index.html`, I run this JQuery to grab the specific table and display it on a div of `id="content"`.

`$("#content").load("proxy.php .infobox");`

But then the table is loaded into browser memory and I can't manipulate it with JQuery to use `removeAttr()`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your attributes inside callback, as AJAX call is asynchronous:

```
$("#content").load("proxy.php .infobox",function(){
    // modify loaded data now
});
```